# Read multiple txt and create df for each with names from original files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Folder has five or six .csv files. I want to read all of them in at once using pd.read_csv() but then save each df as a variable in jupyter specific to the filename without any path or file type.

For example, say these are the two files:

```
'../main/data/csv_files/file_1.csv'
'../main/data/csv_files/file_2.csv'
```

I can do this to each:

```
file_1 = pd.read_csv('../main/data/csv_files/file_1.csv')
file_2 = pd.read_csv('../main/data/csv_files/file_2.csv')
```

However, my question is how could I do this all at once with a loop or something for all files with keeping the naming convention of the filenames?

I can use glob or other means to get a list of all the filepaths for the csv file. I can then create a dictionary to put them all into but it uses their full filepaths as the name.

```
path = r'../main/data/csv_files'
files = glob.glob(path + '/*.csv')

dfs = {}
for x in files:
    dfs[x] = pd.read_csv(x)
```

This works but the naming of the full path isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If your file names are not coming in from an untrusted source like the network, use `exec` to run a python command.

```
import ntpath

for x in files:
    # /a/b/c.csv => c.csv
    file_without_path = ntpath.basename(x) 

    # c.csv => c
    file_without_extension = file_without_path[:-4] 

    # execute "c = pd.readcsv('a/b/c.csv')"
    exec("{} = pd.read_csv('{}')".format(file_without_extension, x))
```

Don't do this if the file names cannot be trusted since any code in the filename will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do -- create dynamic local variables with the same name as a file is a pattern that I've not come across frequently, and is likely to be problematic, however I've shown a way to do that too below. You should instead try to work with the dict keys directly. You could create a dict subclass where you could access the keys as attributes, similar to how pandas allows columns to be accessed either as an attribute or using the regular dict `__getitem__` mechanism. For e.g.,

```
  class AttributeDict(dict):
      """Access keys as attributes."""

      @classmethod
      def _forbidden(cls, key):
          """Key not allowed if it matches a class (not instance) attribute."""
          return key in dir(cls)

      def __setitem__(self, key, val):
          """Regular dict setitem + attribute set."""
          # key must be a regular python identifier, in order to be accesible as
          # an attribute.
          if not str.isidentifier(key):
              raise ValueError("'%s' it not a valid Python identifier. "
                               "Cannot set attribute." % key)

          # Prevent accidentally overwriting an important class attribute.
          if self._forbidden(key):
              raise ValueError("Key '%s' is a class attribute" % key)

          super().__setitem__(key, val)
          setattr(self, key, val)

      def __delitem__(self, key):
          """Regular dict delitem + attribute removal."""
          super().__delitem__(key)
          delattr(self, key)
```

This class is not complete yet since it doesn't prevent setting an attribute directly which could make the dict key values to go out of sync.

```
In [4]: x = AttributeDict()                                                                                                                                        
In [5]: x['A'] = 1                                                                                                                                                 
In [6]: x['2A'] = 1                                                                                                                                                

ValueError: '2A' it not a valid Python identifier. Cannot set attribute.

In [7]: x['B'] = 2                                                                                                                                                 
In [8]: x.A                                                                                                                                                        
Out[8]: 1
In [9]: x.B                                                                                                                                                        
Out[9]: 2
```

Your specific use case would look like:

```
dfs = AttributeDict()
for x in files:
    dfs[x] = pd.read_csv(x)

dfs.file1
dfs.file2
```

Now, to answer the original question, you can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals).

```
for x in files:
    if not str.isidentifier(x):
        raise ValueError("'%s' not a valid identifier." % x)
    locals()[x] = pd.read_csv(x)
```

A filename that is a valid identifier but that clashes with an important local variable will wreak havoc! For e.g., if you are in an IPython session and you do `locals()['exit'] = None`, you can use the `exit` command anymore!